Eliminar el dialogo de MaterialAlertDialogBuilder al pasar a otro fragmento (Kotlin)
Estoy haciendo una aplicación en koklin donde hay varios fragmentos, pero al mostrar un alerta dialogo en un fragmento y cerrarlo, y luego al pasar a otro fragmento y si me devuelvo al fragmento anterior reaparece la ventana de dialogo sin cerrarse.
Como hago para que no vuelva aparecer este alerta dialogo, he intentado de varias formas y no he podido.
Este es un pedaso del codigo de la ventana de dialogo que reaparece al pasar otro fragmento:
class VehicleMenuFragment : Fragment() {
        private lateinit var vehicleMenuBinding: FragmentVehicleMenuBinding
        private lateinit var vehicleMenuViewModel: VehicleMenuViewModel
    
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
            vehicleMenuViewModel.findPaperworkServerDone.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->
                onFindPaperworkServerDoneSubscribe(result)
            }
    
            vehicleMenuBinding.penaltiesButton.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(VehicleMenuFragmentDirections.actionVehicleMenuFragmentToVehicleFragment())
    
            }
        }
    
        private fun onFindPaperworkServerDoneSubscribe(paperworkServer: PaperworkServer?) {
    
            if (paperworkServer == null) {
    
                MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext()) //al ejecutar este dialogo y pasar o otro fragmento y devolverse a este reaparece el diagolo
                    .setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.title_2))
                    .setMessage(resources.getString(R.string.title_3))
                    .setNegativeButton("cerrar") { dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel() }
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show()
    
            } else {
                MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
                    .setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.title))
                    .setMessage(resources.getString(R.string.title_4))
                    .setNegativeButton("cerrar") { dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel() }
                    .create()
                    .show()
            }
        }
    }


Donde estas usando este codigo con el .show() ? en que parte del ciclo de vida del fragmento

Hola user, bienvenido, creo que deberías poner un poco más de contexto (código) para que te puedan ayudar, sin trabajar a ciegas.

Me gustaria saber si encontrate solucion a este proglema? graciass

@ricardohenriquez la solución es simplemente remover el observer cuando el fragmento se destruye, agrego respuesta

Debes eliminar el Observer cuando el Fragment se va a destruir, (pausa -> destrucción), lo cual sucede en onDestroyView()
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
       //* Elimina Observer
      vehicleMenuViewModel.findPaperworkServerDone.removeObservers(viewLifecycleOwner)
    }

